# CSS: allow a container to grow in increments only

Tags: html, css

I want to grow a container, but only when there is enough space to add a new element. Say my elements are 100px, this would mean the acceptable widths for my container would be 120, 230, 340, and so on.

Although I am demoing flex and margin-right: auto, I do not want the margins between the objects to be variable. I want only about 10 pixels between objects. I'm ok with there being a variable horizontal buffer for the container, if that is a solution.

I'm not certain I can do this using flex, so if there's a better way, I'd be grateful.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.panel {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex?

Comment: You need to consider border width too. Your container and panel both have border width of 3px.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're really asking is how to avoid extra space at the end of the container after all the blocks within it are laid out?

Comment: Yes! Richard that is correct, which I can do if I evenly space them, but I don't want a highly variable space between them. I want about 10 to 20 pixels between. That small amount can vary, but it can't be more than 20 pixels.

Comment: There may be an easy solution that I'm missing, but I can see why the browser would have difficulty doing this: It needs to lay out the container; then it has to layout the contents; then it would need to go back and resize the container, which would affect other elements, which would affect the container, which would affect its contents... I considered `calc` to calculate the width of the container in advance, but unfortunately it only supports the simplest arithmetic operators and you'd probably need a `floor()` function at least.

Answer (score -1):

There is the CSS code for the container element :

(added width: fit-content with a padding.)

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: fit-content;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding : .5rem .5rem;
}
```

Comment: @RichardHunter Then I didn't understand. What more do you want?